# data from locked phone

Tags: android, service

I wrote something like this and I can run it but it is not working. Anybody help ? Please be patient :D
I need to save data from accelerometer when phone is locked and I have it in my pocket.
Thanks

**MainActivity:**

```
package emzet.acc2txt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btnStart, btnStop;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
}

public void onStartClick(View view) {
    startService(new Intent(this,accService.class));
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
}

public void onStopClick(View view) {
    stopService(new Intent(this, accService.class));
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
}



}
```

**MyService:**

```
package emzet.acc2txt;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class accService extends Service implements SensorEventListener{

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
protected static SensorManager sensorManager;
protected static Sensor accelerometer;
private FileWriter writer;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if(writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(root + "/pokus.txt",true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    String s = time.format(new java.util.Date());
    try {
        writer.write(s+"\t"+x+"\t"+y+"\t"+z+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Any help ?
I edited manifest too of course...

Comment: You probably need a partial wakelock, but be aware it will drain your battery to do this.

Comment: This code doesn't even work when phone is not locked.
I don't know if I do not have a misatek in my code or something . Shoul it work as it is wrote ?
I am new to android and java and this is my second app :/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set `sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);` in OnCreate in your Service.